How to add an inline element after a line-clamped element?
I'm having trouble figuring how to add an inline element by the end of a text block using a line-clamp. The element could be a  tag or a hoverable icon in order to display a tooltip.
As I need to use display: -webkit-box, is it even possible ?
This question does not solve as it suggests it would be possible to add text. I need to position a DOM element
Example below


.line-clamped {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inline-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
<p class="line-clamped">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<span class="inline-icon"></span>



Expected result


.line-clamped {

}

.inline-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
<p class="line-clamped">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...
     <a href="#">Link</a>
     <span class="inline-icon"></span>
</p>




you mean after the 3 dots?

I'm not clear exactly where you want the icon to be displayed - over the 3 dots, to the right (so space is made available for it), or where...?

@TemaniAfif Yes, after the dots so that the elements do not display under the text

Thanks for adding more clarity, but I'm still not entirely sure what you want. What is to happen if the 3 dots are really close up against the right hand side? Where should the link etc go then - or are you wanting them to essentially be part of the text so space is reserved for them?

@AHaworth I would like them to be part of the text

Thanks for the clarification, are you certain that the answer given by @TemaniAfif in the question marked as a duplicate won't let you include elements as well as just text?

@AHaworth not sure why you reopened the question, The duplicate is adding an inline element at the end like the OP wanted (There is a span in the code that can be any element with any content). PS: most people don't even bother to read the duplicate before saying "the duplicate doesn't work for me"

@TemaniAfif sorry, yes, a bit trigger happy, I had realised that your solution (described as 'hacky', but seems OK) allowed for an element(s), so I asked if it had indeed solved the problem.

@TemaniAfif The duplicate does not answer the problematic. Even though the hacky solutions could be a good fit, cases happen where words or even letters are not perfectly cut before the  element appears, hence why the use of line-clamp isn't negotiable. The duplicates do show a way to add inline elements after texts but not using the line-clamp CSS property. I hope this clarify things

You can add a container with relative positioning and place the icon to the right and bottom of that container.


.container {
  position: relative;
}

p {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 24px;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
<div class="container">
   <p>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   <span></span>
</div>




Close but not quite, the element should appear to be part of the text block instead of cutting any space on the side with a padding
